# Weird NullPointerException with Date object

Tags: java, android, date, nullpointerexception

I have a crash report from a user which i couldn't recreate same error myself on my test device.

Here is the relevant code :

```
        for(File f : sessionDirectory.listFiles()){
        Date lastModDate = new Date(f.lastModified());
    /*Line 53*/ Session ss = new Session(lastModDate.toLocaleString() , f.getName()) ;
        sessionArrayList.add(ss ) ;
    }
```

and here are the stack traces :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain/com.mydomain.myActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mydomain.myActivity.onCreate(myActivity.java:53)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen things like that when concerting dates to/from string representations in java (not android) and for a long time didn't have a clue why. I don't remember the exact details, but it had something to do with a conversion method not being thread safe, which was weird, because (if I remember correctly) it happened in a call to a static jdk method.

Try if it still happens when you pull lastModDate.toLocaleString() into a synchronized method and using an instance of DateFormat.

There was already a bug file against this in the jdk when I looked for it, but it was rejected.

(Perhaps toLocaleString uses a DateFormat attached to the current locale which is shared between all threads, and calls a non-threadsafe method.)

However this is just a guess, but since the symptoms are similarly weird, just give it a try.

Comment: Since you couldn't reproduce the error, trying out whether above suggestion works will be difficult... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Stack trace says:

> Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.mydomain.myActivity.onCreate(myActivity.java:53)

What is line 53?

`sessionDirectory` can be `null` and `sessionDirectory.listFiles()` can return `null` - also got reminded of that by a user crash report :-)

Comment: line 53 is : `Session ss = new Session(lastModDate.toLocaleString() , f.getName()) ;`

Comment: I don't suspect from sessionDirectory.listFiles() and f can be null because line 52 does not cause the problem which i use f.lastModified() in it.